# Grok.match hangs

Tags: regex, multithreading, match, freeze, grok

One of our application keeps readying static files and does a regex a match using grok.match. After around 30 mins of data processing it gets hanged Grok.match. When I took a jstack it shows thread state is runnable, but still it never comes out of the match loop. I took multiple jstack very min to verify this and our application stops producing output. Need help to understand if grock match has some known issue.

Below is thread stack.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3461)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1248)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:637)
at com.google.code.regexp.Matcher.find(Unknown Source)
at oi.thekraken.grok.api.Grok.match(Grok.java:310)
```

Comment: More likely your regex suffers from Catastrophic Backtracking. What is your regex?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide your grok pattern. thanks